# How do i keep precision when applying math formulas into new lists?

Tags: c#

This list has 5 objects, if i subtract the first object with the second: [0]-[1] and put it into a new List it works.  But look at this: [2]-[3], [4]-[5] =? notice that i have [4] as my 5th item, but yet i dont have a '6th item':[5] because this list only has 5 things, what am i subtracting? will i get an error/exception?

```
        var wqat = 1.1;
        var rat = .2;
        var eat = .8;
        var baat = 1.2;
        var baat2 = 1.8;

        List<double> test = new List<double>(); 
        List<double> theOneList = new List<double>();

        theOneList.Add(wqat);
        theOneList.Add(rat);
        theOneList.Add(eat);
        theOneList.Add(baat);
        theOneList.Add(baat2);

        theOneList = theOneList.OrderByDescending(z => z).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            test.Add(theOneList[i] - theOneList[i + 1]);
            Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
        }
```

im getting a system out of range exception when trying to subtract, a possible solution im trying to implement is if the list is 'odd', then just add '0' to the list and it'l make it an even number of objects, so that i can peacefully subtract 2 numbers at a time.

Comment: `theOneList.OrderByDescending(z => z).ToList();` is useless since you've dropped the result.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your lack of decimal precision. Have a feeling there's something you didn't show us...

Comment: same here. works fine after fixing the compiler errors and the index out of range problem.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Explain, and i need a function that add's '0' to the list if the list has an odd number of objects because i cant subtract a piece of the list to an out-of-range object, and thanks

Comment: @Adan - That statement returns a *new* list that you are not assigning to anything. So that new, ordered list isn't used.

Comment: @Adan: Probably you want to *assign* the result of Linq, like this: `theOneList = theOneList.OrderByDescending(z => z).ToList();`, note `theOneList = `

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot  then how do i order the list by descent and then apply my subtracting function? i need this ordered before i can subtract it, and thanks

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you got it, i applied the change and now im getting double's, thank you,

Comment: `theOneList.Sort((i,j) => j.CompareTo(i))` would sort in-place.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko how do i prevent system out of range exceptions when the list is odd?

Comment: @Adan: do not use *magic numbers*: what does `4` in the for loop mean? `i < theOneList.Count - 1` is the right code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of the comments above:

```
  var wqat = 1.1;
  var rat = .2;
  var eat = .8;
  var baat = 1.2;
  var baat2 = 1.8;

  // Add's are hard to read
  List<double> theOneList = new List<double>() {
    wqat, rat, eat, baat, baat2 
  };

  // Inplace sorting, "-" for the descending order
  theOneList.Sort((x, y) => -x.CompareTo(y));

  // Or (worse) Linq, do not forget to assign the result
  // theOneList = theOneList.OrderByDescending(z => z).ToList();

  List<double> test = new List<double>(); 

  // No magic numbers (i.e. 4) - no pesky out of range exceptions
  for (int i = 0; i < theOneList.Count - 1; ++i)
    test.Add(theOneList[i] - theOneList[i + 1]);

  // Output (mix output and algorthim is not a good idea)
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, test));
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for (int i = 0; i < theOneList.Count - 1; ++i)
{
    test.Add(theOneList[i] - theOneList[i + 1]);
        Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
}
```

to avoid index out of range